# how to modify strings in a list of strings

Tags: python, string

I would like to take a list of strings which represent individual lines entered in a CLI and put '~$ ' at the beginning so when I display them it is more clear that they are command lines.  I tried this

```
command = # a multiline block of command lines
lines = command.split('\n')
for l in lines:
    l = '~$ ' + l
for l in lines: print l
```

But this modifies the temporary variable l I think without going back and changing the actual value in the list.  If I put the print inside of the first loop it prints with the correct values, but if I do it like shown the change isn't made.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you make any attempt at all to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
lines = ['~$ ' + line for line in command.split('\n')]
```

If you *have* to use a for loop, you'd use `enumerate()` to include an index so you can replace the individual items in the list:

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    lines[i] = '~$ ' + line
```

Comment: @mgilson: tsk, tsk, have you not yet learned that I keep on editing for a while? :-P

Comment: note the new binding here, in case this is a global variable or something.

Comment: I think I prefer slice-assignment here (over `enumerate` with the loop):  `lines[:] = ['~$ '+line for line in lines]`

Comment: @mgilson: if the list is references elsewhere, sure.

Comment: the `enumerate` solution can be a bit misleading - it looks like independent values.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I know you edit.  But, if I edit, then there's a record and it doesn't look like you dropped a fantastically long/complete answer all at once ;-).  We've gotta keep you honest somehow ...

Comment: thanks for the help, those kinds of assignments have always baffled me so I never think to use them.

Answer (score 1):

The functional way:

```
list(map(lambda s: '~$ ' + s, command.splitlines()))
```